# Подсветка пункта меню именно в тот момент, когда до него проскролили

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы активный (выбранный пункт меню) подсвечивался непосредственно при выполнении определенного условия (когда проскролились до нужного элемента). Условие я задам потом сама, на данный момент функция срабатывает при клике на пункт меню, но не реагирует на условие. То есть работает сама перемотка и изменение цвета, а нужно, чтобы это происходило строго с учетом условия. Спасибо.

```
const scrollToTarget = (e) => {

    const targetId = e.target.getAttribute('to');
    const target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    const targetPosition = getPosition(target);
    const offsetTargetPosition = targetPosition - navigationHeight;
    window.scrollTo({
      top: offsetTargetPosition,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    const elem = e.target;
    if (elem.getBoundingClientRect().y === 47) {
      elem.setAttribute('style', 'color: green');
    } else elem.setAttribute('style', 'color: blue');
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    navLinks[i].addEventListener('click', scrollToTarget);
  }
```

Comment: то есть, у Вас никогда не срабатывает `elem.setAttribute('style', 'color: green');`?

Comment: У меня верно срабатывает условие, но! при клике на пункт меню. То есть выбирается правильный цвет и отрабатывает скроллинг. А мне нужно, чтобы цвет менялся не при клике сразу, а когда доскроллил до нужного элемента. Сеттаймаутом это хорошо задается, но это не оптимально, тк должен еще отрабатывать елсе,  а сеттаймаут окрашивает насовсем.

Comment: другими словами, Вам нужен `callback`, который сработает как только `window.scrollTo` закончиться?

Comment: возможно) колбэк я плохо знаю, к тому же у меня идет условие внутри функции.. Я не очень  понимаю, как правильно это записать

Comment: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292603/is-there-a-callback-for-window-scrollto) дан ответ как можно самодельно вставить коллбек по окончанию скролла, но если не разберетесь, то отпишите снова

Comment: переписала с помощью промисов, но не работает. Или это в корне разные вещи? А с колбэком я не могу его верно передать в функцию.

Comment: и еще такой момент, нужно, чтобы пункт меню был активным только, когда выбран этот пункт, при переходе на другой пункт цвет должен становиться прежним

Comment: а как там промис должен был работать?) скажите, Ваш проект есть на git? лучше в живую посмотреть

Comment: Про промис я предположила последовательно запускать функции (на скролинг и на изменение цвета). Нет, на гите нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ладно.. рискну предложить **теоретически** рабочий вариант

```
const scrollToTarget = e => {
    const targetId = e.target.getAttribute('to');
    const target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    const targetPosition = getPosition(target);
    const offsetTargetPosition = targetPosition - navigationHeight;
    const elem = e.target;

    window.addEventListener('scroll', customScrollTo); // после запуска scrollToTarget мы вешаем прослушивание на событие scroll

    window.scrollTo({
      top: offsetTargetPosition,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

    // эта функция будет проверять когда скролл дойдет до элемента каждую прокрутку станицы
    function customScrollTo() {
        if (window.pageYOffset === offsetTargetPosition) {  // если скролл дошел до элемента 
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', customScrollTo); // удаляем прослушивание

            elem.style.color = elem.getBoundingClientRect().y === 47 ? 'green' : 'blue';  // и меняем цвет
        }
    }
};

for (let i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
  navLinks[i].addEventListener('click', scrollToTarget);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!) Работает) Единственный нюанс, цвет меняется насовсем, то есть, когда мы уходим с предыдущего пункта меню, условие меняется, по идее, а цвет остается.

Comment: @Dasha,  ого.. тогда сделайте внутри `customScrollTo` (внутри успешного блока `if`) метод, который очищает у всех `navLinks` инлайновые стили (чтобы все `navLinks` вернулись в предыдущее состояние). если не получится - напишите снова

Comment: Получилось!!! Но без доработки) Я пока Ваш код внимательно разбирала, у меня заработало все)) разница, как я поняла, в том, что я не стала удалять слушателя (просто потому что еще с таким не сталкивалась). Это совпадение или имеет логику? Здесь где-то можно код вставить, который работает?

Comment: @Dasha, это, кстати, прекрасное совпадение имеющее логику, но есть и минус - если Вы не удалите слушателя, то он будет постоянно работать, даже если он не нужен. это лишняя нагрузка на сайт. учтите это

Comment: @Dasha, а зачем вставлять уже рабочий код?) эту тему и так кроме меня никто не читает, а я Вам на слово верю. кстати, не забывайте отметить мой ответ как *правильный*, чтобы все видели, что я здесь главный) а то никто до сих пор не верит в это

Comment: ))) это стрелочка вверх у поста? Так я ее сразу нажала, а мне говорят, типа спасибо за отзыв, но у Вас репутация ни о чем, поэтому мы его отображать не будем)

Comment: @Dasha, стрелочка *вверх* поста - это просто одобрить ответ (лайкнуть что ли). а у автора вопроса есть еще и опция отметить вопрос как правильный, но это, на самом деле, не важно, так как я всё равно не стремлюсь к славе, а сверх-популярность мне только навредит

Comment: Нашла) Это галка)

Comment: Дабожежмой! Призовись! Я не найду, как тебе сообщение отправить)

Comment: @Dasha, ввввоу..
у Вас получилось сделать моё утро особенный.
я Вас слушаю, принцесса

Comment: Ты реакт хорошо знаешь?

Comment: @Dasha, когда как) линканите вопрос, который Вы не можете решить

Comment: Я даже не знаю, это объемно, у меня есть скрипт на jqury и чистом js, его надо переписать на реакт. Сюда эта богалельня не влезает)

Comment: ща в два сообщения попробую прислать

Comment: не, даже кусочек не влезает, превышение символов идет

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 var width = $( window ).width();
 //Запрет скролла по X 
 (function($) { $(window).scroll( function() { $(window).scrollLeft(0); });
})(jQuery);

//Для списка
if (width >= 796) {
 $(".list-main1").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Упс.. Город не найден"
 }); 
 $(".list-main2").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Упс.. Клиника не найдена"
 });

Comment: @Dasha, чекни меня в телеге `@bringmetheaugust`, а там на CodePen перейдем и покажешь